# matlab indexing with multiple condition

Tags: matlab, indexing

I can't figure out how to create a vector based on condition on more than one other vectors. I have three vectors and I need values of one vector if values on other vectors comply to condition. 
As an example below I would like to choose values from vector `a` if values on vector `b==2` and values on vector `c==0` obviously I expect `[2 4]`

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
b = [1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2];
c = [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1]
```

I thought something like:

```
d = a(b==2) & a(c==0)
```

but I have `d =     1     1     1     1     1` not sure why. 
It seems to be basic problem but I can find solution for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case you can consider using `a(b==2 & c==0)`

Comment: can you please advise me what a(b==2) & a(c==0) produces?

Comment: In your case, `b==2` returns a vector of logical values indicating if the equality is satisfied. This vector can be used to access the corresponding elements of a:

    b==2 --> [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1]  
    c==0 --> [1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]  
    (b==2) & (c==0) --> [0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]  
    a((b==2) & (c==0)) --> [2, 4]

Please remark that you need Boolean indices to access element of a in this way. Therefore you cannot use, e.g., 

    a([1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0])

since in this case the 1s and 0s are real numbers while Matlab expects the result of logical operators or 'logical' variables.

Comment: In your case, you have `a(b==2) --> [2 4 6 8 10]`, `a(c==0) --> [1 2 3 4 5]`, then you calculate the "and" of the two vectors, which is true (1) if the corresponding elements are not zero, and false (0) if at least one element is zero. Therefore: `[2&1, 4&2, 6&3, 8&4, 10&5]-->[1 1 1 1 1]`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [ismember](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to find the matching indices along the rows after concatenating `b` and `c` and then index to `a`.

**Code**

```
a(ismember([b;c]',[2 0],'rows'))
```

**Output**

```
ans =

     2
     4
```

You may use [bsxfun](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) too for the same result -

```
a(all(bsxfun(@eq,[b;c],[2 0]'),1))
```

Or you may just tweak your method to get the correct result -

```
a(b==2 & c==0)
```